# VSCode Typescript Intellisense not working in the most simple project setup

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have been using VSCode intellisense happily since quite a long time.

Now I am doing something very simple: create a new project, add a package like rxJs and then start coding.

What I find is that intellisense is not working as it is used to.

In particular, if I just open a file like **test.ts** and add the following innocent code

```
of('abc'). // of is a function of rxJs
```

I get this response from intellisense

[image: intellisense not giving the right support]

At the same time if I start importing manually the function and do `ctrl+space` between the brackets I get the expected help.

[image: here intellisense works]

I am pretty sure I am missing something very basic, but after few hours of browsing I could not find any answer.

Here my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,  
      "noUnusedParameters": true  
    },
    "include": [
      "src/*.ts",
      "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `of` needs to be imported for it to be available in the file.

Error:

```
of('abc'). // of is a function of rxJs
```

No error:

```
import {of} from 'rxjs';
of('abc'). // of is a function of rxJs
```

Comment: This is clear, but in all other projects I have, when I write `of` intellisense suggests where to import it from. This what I am not experiencing in this simple project.

Comment: there is quick fix option and there should be import suggestions. you can open quick fix window with "crrl+."

Comment: @basarat @Juraj Kocan The problem seems to have disappeared just with time. Probably its cause was that I was not giving enough time to VSCode to *become aware* of the existence of `rxJs`. After I left the computer idle for some time, I am not experiencing the problem any more.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Intellisense no longer working, I am unable to import of, filter, map etc.  Have to type the import statement in manually. Quick fix is now useless - asks me if I want to replace  'filter' with 'file'.  Obviously I do not.